# I want to fetch data row by row by using this php code but its occurring error i,e Undefined index: what should i do?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test") or die('error');
$query = "select * from data" ;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    $num_id = $row['id'];
    $arr_question = $row['question'];
    $a = $row['option_a'];
    $b = $row['option_b'];
    $c = $row['option_c'];
    $d = $row['option_d'];
    $answere = $row['answere'];
    $description = $row['description'];
}
?>
```

I want to fetch data from database using this code, but when I use
`mysqli_fetch_array` it returns the last row of the table, and when I
use `mysqli_fetch_row` it returns undefined index.

Now please help me, what should be the right step for me?

Comment: Could you post the result of "select * from data limit 1" ?

Comment: "answer" is misspelled. If it's not misspelled in the "data" table, then .. that might be your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your variables during the `while` loop, therefore at the end of the loop, your variables will contain the values from the last row.

Try storing the values from each row into an array, and then process the array later, you can use an associative array, ex:

```
$results = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    $results[] = array(
                 'num_id'=> $row['id'],
                 'arr_question' => $row['question'],
                 'a' => $row['option_a'],
                 'b' => $row['option_b'],
                 'c' => $row['option_c'],
                 'd' = $row['option_d'],
                 'answer' => $row['answere'],
                 'description' => $row['description']
             );
}

print_r($results);
```